# Jekyll page rating calculator with meta from Front Mater area

Tags: ruby, syntax, jekyll, meta, calculation

I am editing include/span with the following code pretend to be as "Jekyll page rating calculator with meta from Front Mater area" but it seems like some syntax missing an extra heading/lines to let calculation to display in left bottom round quotes. Now there is no value

[image: Fragment]

[See the sampl page](https://indexmod.gq/aberdeen-fashion-week)

```
<span class="indexmod">
{% assign number_of_words = content | strip_html | number_of_words %}
{% assign social = page.facebook | plus: page.instagram %}

{% comment %}Two lines for readability, but can be chained on one line{% 
endcomment %}
{% assign Indexmod = social | times: page.age | divided_by: 1000000.0 %}
{% assign Indexmod = Indexmod | times: number_of_words | divided_by: 100 
 %}
{% endunless %}
 </span>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two reasons why this doesn't work:

- The `{% endunless %}` in this include is missing a matching `unless` clause.  Either add one or remove the `endunless` line.
- The value of `Indexmod` is not printed.  You can do that by adding `{{ Indexmod }}` after your calculations are done.

Comment: Jyrki, can I just swap {% endunless %} with {{ Indexmod }}?

Comment: @AndreiDeinichenko Yes.  That's one possible outcome of my suggestions.